# Search for all rows with values in excel with perl

Tags: perl, excel

I am trying to parse data from excel using perl into a specific XML format, which is read by another application, which then creates a graphical representation of the data. The excel sheet gets updated by data capturers on a regular base. I have opted for the Spreadsheet::Read module but I am having an issue.

The sheet would be divided into specific cells, which corresponds to a specific layout.
The sheet will thus have:

Country | City | Suburb | link

Each row being different data etc.

I tried to tell the script to get every row like this.

```
    use Spreadsheet::Read;

    my $book  = ReadData ("Captured_input.xlsx");
    my @rows = Spreadsheet::Read::rows ($book->[1]);

    print "@rows\n";
```

This however prints ARRAY(and some hex data)
However, I want it to read each row and cell and return it like this:

Country1, City1, Suburb1,link1

Country2, City2, Suburb2,link2

It runs on a daily base so it should not read end of file only, it should read the entire sheet each time, so if any changes were made it will republish the XML.

If I use it like this, it works and returns the data, but I then need to manually specify each row, but I cannot estimate how many rows there will be in future.

```
    use Spreadsheet::Read;

    my $book  = ReadData ("Captured_input.xlsx");
    my @row = Spreadsheet::Read::cellrow ($book->[1], 4);

    print "@row\n,";
```

Some input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. read [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).
2. read [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).
3. read the [Spreadsheet::Read documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aRead).

The documentation shows quite well what data structure the `$book` will contain. Once you understand how references work (see the first two links), handling the data will be easy.

Comment: Hi Amon, Thanks very much. I will look inti them now!